# Rendering independent bones

Tags: opengl-es, gltf, skinning, openxr

I'm trying to render a model of a hand in a 3D space based on the positions given by
the `XrHandJointLocationEXT` array from the [XR_EXT_hand_tracking](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenXR/specs/1.0/html/xrspec.html#XR_EXT_hand_tracking) extension.
I am using both [GTLF hand models from Valve](https://github.com/JoeLudwig/xrsandbox/tree/master/projects/xrsandbox/assets/models/valve_hand_models), which have the correct amount of bones
to match the joints defined by the OpenXR specification in the [XrHandJointEXT](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenXR/specs/1.0/html/xrspec.html#XrHandJointEXT) enum.

I do my rendering as follows :

Every frame I update each joint independently by multiplying its current transform
with the inverse bind matrice retrieved from the GLTF model. The `XrPosef` is relative to the center of the 3D space. I am using [cglm](https://github.com/recp/cglm) to handle all the matrice calculations.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < XR_HAND_JOINT_COUNT_EXT; ++i) {
    const XrHandJointLocationEXT *joint = &locations->jointLocations[i];
    const XrPosef *pose = &joint->pose;

    glm_mat4_identity(model->bones[i]);

    vec3 position;
    wxrc_xr_vector3f_to_cglm(&pose->position, position);
    glm_translate(model->bones[i], position);

    versor orientation;
    wxrc_xr_quaternion_to_cglm(&pose->orientation, orientation);
    glm_quat_rotate(model->bones[i], orientation, model->bones[i]);

    glm_mat4_mul(model->bones[i], model->inv_bind[i], model->bones[i]);
}
```

Then the `bones` array is uploaded to the vertex shader, along with the `view-proj`
matrix, computed for each `eye` of the HMD.

```
#version 320 es"

uniform mat4 vp;
uniform mat4 bones[26];

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tex_coord;
layout (location = 2) in uvec4 joint;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 weight;

out vec2 vert_tex_coord;

void main() {
    mat4 skin =
        bones[joint.x] * weight.x +
        bones[joint.y] * weight.y +
        bones[joint.z] * weight.z +
        bones[joint.w] * weight.w;
    gl_Position = vp * skin * vec4(pos, 1.0);
    vert_tex_coord = tex_coord;
}
```

Is the method of calculation correct? I get decent but "glitchy" results. As you can see
on the following screenshot, i rendered both independant joints on top of the hand
model, and you can see a glitch on the thumb.

[image: screenshot]

Should I take account of the parent bone when computing my bone transform?

Comment: The [glTF Skinning Tutorial](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Tutorials/blob/master/gltfTutorial/gltfTutorial_020_Skins.md) has some additional math & shader code to review, if you think the error might be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to my problem: the joint order from the GTLF model doesn't match the order [XrHandJointEXT](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenXR/specs/1.0/html/xrspec.html#XrHandJointEXT), leading to the right transform being applied to the wrong joint.

In my case, my model defined the `Wrist` node as being the first one and the `Palm` as the last one, where OpenXR defines `XR_HAND_JOINT_PALM_EXT` as the first joint, and `XR_HAND_JOINT_WRIST_EXT` as the second one.

Here's the code for the update function

```
bool
wxrc_hand_model_update(struct wxrc_hand_model *model,
                const XrHandJointLocationEXT *locations)
{
        /*
         * OpenXR defines joint 0 as XR_HAND_JOINT_PALM_EXT, but the valve hand
         * model defines Palm as the last joint
         * TODO: handle this dynamically for other models
         */
        static const size_t convert[26] = {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0
        };

        for (size_t i = 0; i < XR_HAND_JOINT_COUNT_EXT; ++i) {
                const XrHandJointLocationEXT *joint = &locations[convert[i]];
                const XrPosef *pose = &joint->pose;

                mat4 transform = GLM_MAT4_IDENTITY_INIT;

                vec3 position;
                wxrc_xr_vector3f_to_cglm(&pose->position, position);
                glm_translate(transform, position);

                versor orientation;
                wxrc_xr_quaternion_to_cglm(&pose->orientation, orientation);
                glm_quat_rotate(transform, orientation, transform);

                glm_mat4_mul(transform, model->inv_bind[i], model->bones[i]);
        }
        return true;
}
```